# ast.literal_eval() on a dict which has a null key value

Tags: python, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to convert a string to a dictionary using literal_eval(), the only issue I am facing here is I have a null in one of the dictionary values.

```
attributes = '{"New Value": "United States", "Old Value": null, "Reason": "lorem ipsum", "Source": "Action"}'
```

This is my input dict which I am casting into a string before passing to literal_eval().
when I do a literal eval using the code:

```
attributes_new = ast.literal_eval(attributes)
```

and I get this error when the code runs:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <ast.Name object at 0x1066efa30>
```

Is there a way I can replace this null with a None so that it doesn't fail or if there is a better and optimised solution, it is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This is my input dict which I am casting into a string" What? Where are you doing that? What is producing the `null`? This looks like *JSON*. Why are you trying to use `ast.literal_eval`? Just use `json.loads`

Comment: `json.loads(attributes)`?

Comment: I just used json.loads and it seemed to work like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
attributes_new = ast.literal_eval(attributes.replace('null', 'None'))
```

...is what I'd do as it is simple and readable.

---

Edit: I just noticed it looks suspiciously a lot like JSON. Maybe use `json.loads` instead.

Comment: Yup, json.loads did work here. I was a bit skeptical first about using it, but now it makes sense to use that.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use two method to solve this problem-**

- **Using json package**

   You can use direct jason.load pacakge as below to remove null

```py
import json
attributes_None = json.loads(attributes)
```

- **Using ast package**
  First you have to replace null with None

```py
import ast
attributes = attributes.replace('null','None')
new_attributes = ast.literal_eval(attributes)
```